# Issue with Asian languages spaces from PHP var http_referer

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, space, referrer

Trying to extract some keywords from `urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`…

Then `$ref = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $referer);`

Usually, it works fine with western languages, but I often have issues to separate words with Asian languages like here :

`すずめ　焼き`,
`বন মুরগির`,

same issue in Hebrew !

Is there anything more universal than `\s` in `regexp`? Or should I handle `HTTP_REFERER` differently?

Comment: It is a very common thing, use `"/\s+/u"`

Comment: So common… makes you wonder why it's not enabled by default, by now ? Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want to match any Unicode digit with `\d` or any digit or letter with `\w`, the `u` modifier should not be used. See more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).